# Is it possible to save the Caffe's training log in pycaffe?

Tags: pycaffe

Is there a way to capture/save the Caffe's logs which is displayed in console while training?

I would like to save those logs as well. However, since I'm in Jupyter Notebook, I'm having difficulties saving the Jupyter Notebook's console output and can't figure this out.